# Do I still need to use data-ng with AngularJS or can I drop the data-?

Tags: angularjs

In my application data-ng is used everywhere. Can someone tell me why the data- is needed? I read something about HTML5 validation however if I do not care if it is fully validated or not and if I am using browsers that are IE8 and above then do I still need to use the data- ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-*` is only there to enforce validation - if you don't care, there is nothing wrong with just using `ng-*` directives.

Comment: I read that older IEs cannot work correctly without the data-  I wonder if that's the case and which IEs that applies to. I was not able to find anything that gave more details.

Comment: 1. It is not "enforcing" validation - it is more like "allowing" it. 2. If you are looking for a framework supporting older version of IE, Angular is not the one for you :) (They officially dropped support of IE8 in the latest 1.3 version - and I couldn't be more happy about it.)